# iphone week-view calendar to show reservations

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, icalendar

I am looking to build an iphone application to show booking/reservations of a Device. I want to have a week view where I can show the reservations using different colors (Something similar to the one in Google Calendar).

I saw few projects in github which provides month-view, but i could not find the one with week-view.

I am pretty new to iPhone development, and I would appreciate if someone can help me in this regard. Some tutorials which helps in adding an calendar to an application.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you create a google calender and then let the users of your app look at the booking on there. If that is what you want here is the official doc for objective-c

[GDataObjCIntroduction - gdata-objectivec-client - Introduction for Objective-C Developers - Project Hosting on Google Code](http://code.google.com/p/gdata-objectivec-client/wiki/GDataObjCIntroduction)

google code project that access google calendar
[iphone-gcal - Project Hosting on Google Code](http://code.google.com/p/iphone-gcal/)

another client
[Downloads - gdata-objectivec-client - Project Hosting on Google Code](http://code.google.com/p/gdata-objectivec-client/downloads/list)

a tutorial
[How To Use Google APIs with iPhone SDK](http://johntwang.com/blog/2009/06/08/how-to-use-google-apis-with-iphone-sdk/)

Hope this helps.

Comment: @MacNOOb: thanks for your reply? But is it possbile to show the calendar on the iPhone. I can see that we can interact with the Google Calendar API's. But how can i show the calendar within my app?

Comment: There should be a view that you can implement that shows the calender. If not, you can always set up a webView and then direct the device to the actual google calendar page that people are putting data into. Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks..I will look into it..But defintely seems to be a lot of work

Comment: Not really, just create a view for the UIWebView for example http://www.iphonesdkarticles.com/2008/08/uiwebview-tutorial.html Just point it at the the google account that the calendar is being hosted in. Really you should just be pasting in the URL

Comment: Not the webview, but updating the Google calendar from iPhone :)

Comment: @MacN00b How can we get Event Color from iphone-gcal-example ?